# Sliding multiple video files with bxslider

Tags: javascript, html, bxslider

I'm using the bxslider in google chrome and my videos don't appear in the slider panel. They just appear one after the other vertically on the page. Here is the javascript code I put inside of the head.

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
      });
</script>
```

Here is the div element that holds my videos and is inside of the body.

```
<div class="bxslider">
<div>
<iframe src="videos/video1.mp4" height="400" width="800" id="video1"></iframe>
</div>

<div>
<iframe src="videos/video2.mp4" height="400" width="800" id="video2"></iframe>
</video></div>

<div>
<iframe src="videos/video3.mp4" height="400" width="800" id="video3"></iframe>
</div>

<div>
<iframe src="videos/video4.mp4" height="400" width="800" id="video4"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is what happens when the plugin fails to run due to an error--it's what the HTML looks like by default.

Seems to work once the errant `video` tag is removed. You also had a misspelled closing `div` tag.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/XWL9Y/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});
```

Consider validating your HTML next time you run into an issue. http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input